# Syntax to assign values to dynamic class members in PHP?

Tags: php, class, syntax, member

I have a class with a structure as follows:

```
class Test {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function __construct($params) {

        foreach($params as $key => $value) {

            $this->$key = $value;

        }

    }

}
```

The idea is that I can pass any number of parameters when instantiating a new object as I see fit. So for example I can do:

```
$params['var2'] = "Variable 2 Instantiated";
$params['var3'] = "Test";
$test = new Test($params);
```

Which would only instantiate $test->var2 and $test->var3.

Up until now, I've been writing a list of assignments, but if I want to instantiate an object with only half the available members, I have to check if values have been set etc.

SO the actual question is:

What is the correct syntax for assigning values to dynamic class members?

```
$this->$var = $var2
```

As per my example, is not working. I tried Googling with no luck.

Comment: Your sample code looks correct, and it is working [in this demo](http://viper-7.com/wR5YHT)

Comment: Hmm, thanks, will investigate further, must have a problem elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and step through your code - you'll have made an invalid assumption somewhere, like misspelling the constructor

Comment: For cleaner code, I would suggest this syntax:  $object->{$property}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example already works perfectly. [See it working on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/tMP4PdE3).